# Power BI DAX Measure doesn't work with ALL() (filter unfiltered Data)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm pretty new here and also with Power BI and DAX. So please excuse rookie mistakes and dirty code and also bad english :P

So, I created a measure with many variables to spit out a number from 1-12 (clock).
To get to this I have to calculate in 3 different times. One current Date, one which goes back 3 quartals from the current and one which goes back 6 quartals (Current, Shortterm, Longterm). This is the setup. So I have to filter my Data first and then calculate with it.

First, I just wanted to set a Date (01.10.2021) which is fix.
But now I wanted to be dynamic. I wanted the user to choose the "current" date. Or mainly I wanted to put it in a line plot and let the visual do the slicing (with Date on the x-axis) to show development in time. But here my problem begins.

The Problem is - I guess - that I wanted Data to filter which are unaffected from extern filter (from the Visual or slicer)

I tried out the ALL() Function for the calculation so that it will not be affected from the extern slicer. The result is 0. I think I don´t really understand the mechanics behind the ALL() Function and its  brother and sister functions, what they do and what they don't do. The docs explanation was also not helpful. I know I did't try out many things but I sat here a few hours and really can't figure things out.

Here is a part of the DAX from the old measure which is relevant for the problem:

```
OLD clock= 

VAR _SHORTTERM = 3
VAR _LONGTERM = 6

VAR _CURRENT_DATE = DATE(2020,10,01)

VAR _SHORT_TERM_DATE = PREVIOUSDAY(
                        FIRSTDATE(
                            DATESINPERIOD(
                                'Date'[Date],
                                _CURRENT_DATE,
                                -(3*_SHORTTERM),
                                MONTH)
                                ))

VAR _LONG_TERM_DATE = PREVIOUSDAY(
                        FIRSTDATE(
                            DATESINPERIOD(
                                'Date'[Date],
                                _CURRENT_DATE,
                                -(3*_LONGTERM),
                                MONTH)
                                ))

VAR _CURRENT_AVERAGE =  CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(
        Facts_Values[Value]),
        'Facts_Values'[Quarter] == _CURRENT_DATE
        )

VAR _LONGTERM_AVERAGE =  CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(
        Facts_Values[Value]),
        'Facts_Values'[Quarter] == _LONG_TERM_DATE
        )

VAR _SHORTTERM_AVERAGE = CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(
        Facts_Values[Value]),
        'Facts_Values'[Quarter] == _SHORT_TERM_DATE
        )

VAR _LONGTERM_AVERAGE_RELATIVE = (_CURRENT_AVERAGE - _LONGTERM_AVERAGE) / (_LONGTERM - 1)

VAR _SHORTTERM_AVERAGE_RELATIVE = (_CURRENT_AVERAGE - _SHORTTERM_AVERAGE) / (_SHORTTERM - 1)

..
..
..
VAR _ALL = ROUNDDOWN((12 * (RDV+YDV+IDV+RLV+YLV+ILV)),0)+ 1 )
Return _ALL
```

And then my "dynamic" version

```
New Clock = 

VAR _SHORTTERM = 3
VAR _LONGTERM = 6

VAR _CURRENT_DATE = DATE(
    (YEAR(
        MIN('Date'[Date]))),MONTH(MIN('Date'[Date])),01)

VAR _SHORT_TERM_DATE = PREVIOUSDAY(
                        FIRSTDATE(
                            DATESINPERIOD(
                                'Date'[Date],
                                _CURRENT_DATE,
                                -(3*_SHORTTERM),
                                MONTH)
                                ))

VAR _LONG_TERM_DATE = PREVIOUSDAY(
                        FIRSTDATE(
                            DATESINPERIOD(
                                'Date'[Date],
                                _CURRENT_DATE,
                                -(3*_LONGTERM),
                                MONTH)
                                ))

VAR _CURRENT_AVERAGE =  CALCULATE(CALCULATE(
        AVERAGEX(ALL(Facts_Values),
        Facts_Values[Value])),
        'Facts_Values'[Quarter from] == _CURRENT_DATE
        )

VAR _LONGTERM_AVERAGE =  CALCULATE(CALCULATE(
    AVERAGEX(ALL(Facts_Values),
        Facts_Values[Value])),
        'Facts_Values'[Quarter from] == _LONG_TERM_DATE
        )

VAR _SHORTTERM_AVERAGE = CALCULATE(CALCULATE(
    AVERAGEX(ALL(Facts_Values),
        Facts_Values[Values])),
        'Facts_Values'[Quarter from] == _SHORT_TERM_DATE
        )

VAR _LONGTERM_AVERAGE_RELATIVE = (_CURRENT_AVERAGE - _LONGTERM_AVERAGE) / (_LONGTERM - 1)

VAR _SHORTTERM_AVERAGE_RELATIVE = (_CURRENT_AVERAGE - _SHORTTERM_AVERAGE) / (_SHORTTERM - 1)

.. 
.. 
.. 

VAR _ALL = ROUNDDOWN((12 * (RDV+YDV+IDV+RLV+YLV+ILV)),0)+ 1 )
Return _ALL
```

Hope to find some friendly experts to solve my problem.